# Circuits in a linear oriented matroid

Tags: linear-algebra, oriented-matroids

Given $E$ a finite subset of a real vector space $V$, a **circuit** of the associated matroid is a minimal linearly dependent subset of $E$. For each circuit $\underline C$, a minimal linear dependence
$$\sum_{v\in \underline C}\lambda_vv=0$$ gives rise to a **signed circuit** $C = (C^+,C^-)$ defined by $$C^+= \{v\in \underline C: \lambda_v>0\}$$ and $$C^-=\{v\in \underline C:\lambda_v<0\}.$$ (So $(C^-,C^+)$ is also a signed circuit.)

Given an arbitrary linear dependence of the form
$$\sum_{v\in S\subset E}\lambda_v v = 0$$ with $\lambda_v\neq 0$ for all $v\in S$, by definition there is a circuit $\underline C$ with $\underline C\subset S$.

My question is: if we define $S^+ = \{v\in S:\lambda_v>0\}$ and $S^-=\{v\in S:\lambda_v<0\}$, must there exist a *signed* circuit $C$ with $C^+\subset S^+$ and $C^-\subset S^-$? Certainly not every circuit $\underline C\subset S$ has such a signature, but it seems easy enough to find one in particular examples by ad hoc means.

If it's useful or necessary, for my purposes I am only interested in situations where all coefficients are integers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If the dependence is minimal, then $(S^+, S^-)$ is a signed circuit. Now suppose that the dependence is not minimal. Then there is a subset $T\subsetneq S$ and a dependence 
$$\sum_{v\in T} \mu_v v =0$$
with $\mu_v \neq 0$ for all $v \in T$. Define $\mu_v=0$ for $v\in S\setminus T$. Let $t$ be the smallest positive real number such that $\lambda_v+t\mu_v=0$ or $\lambda_v-t\mu_v=0$ for some $v\in S$. Without loss of generality, suppose that the first case happened. Let $\rho_v=\lambda_v+t\mu_v$ for all $v\in S$. Then 
$$\sum_{v\in T} \rho_v v =0,$$
there is a $u\in S\setminus T$ such that $\rho_u\neq 0$, there is a $w\in T$ such that $\rho_w=0$, and for all $v \in S$, we have $\lambda_v\rho_v \ge 0$. In other words, we obtained a smaller dependence $S_1 \subsetneq S$, where $S_1^+\subseteq S^+$ and $S_1^-\subseteq S^-$. A signed circuit is then obtained by induction.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you explain why there is a $u\in T$ with $\rho_u\neq 0$, please? It seems to me that if there were some $T\subsetneq S$ such that $\sum_{v\in T}\lambda_vv=0$, then taking $\mu_v = -\lambda_v$ for $v\in T$ we would have $t=1$ and $\rho_v=0$ for all $v\in T$.

Comment: On further reflection my counterexample above isn't relevant - you can assume without loss of generality that $\sum_{v\in T}\lambda_vv\neq 0$ for each $T\subsetneq S$, as otherwise you could just pass to this analysis on such a $T$.

Comment: Is this fact written down somewhere (outside of MO, I mean)? I would like to cite it in my work.

Comment: @Brad  sorry for the confusion, I made a mistake: the $u$ should be taken from $S\setminus T$. Then it follows from the choice $\mu_u=0$. I am editing the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Brad  this proof is analogous to the proof of [Radon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%27s_theorem). It also very likely follows from the theory of oriented matroids. For example, by Proposition 3.7.2 in the book "Oriented matroids" by Bjorner et al. (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1744046).

Comment: @Brad What's wrong with citing MathOverflow?